# asp.net dropDownList selected value null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am making a school application about articles publication. In a dropdownList I want to display the value that exists in database as default pre-selected value. DropdownList conatins "emertimi" from table "kategorite". When user selects a value it saves id of "kategoria_id" in table "artikulli". Here is my code behind

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.EditItem)
            {
                DropDownList drpdKategoria = e.Item.FindControl("drpdKategoria") as DropDownList;
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);
                string Qry = "select * from kategoria";
                string id = Request.QueryString["id"];
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(Qry, con);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
                DataSet ds3 = new DataSet();
                con.Open();
                da.Fill(ds);
                string kategoria_id = "select kategoria_id from artikulli where id='" + id + "'";
                SqlDataAdapter dk = new SqlDataAdapter(kategoria_id, con);
                dk.Fill(ds2);
                var kategoria_id_result = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]);
                string emertimi = "select emertimi from kategoria where id='" + kategoria_id_result + "'";
                SqlDataAdapter de = new SqlDataAdapter(emertimi, con);
                de.Fill(ds3);

                drpdKategoria.DataSource = ds;
                drpdKategoria.DataValueField = "id";
                drpdKategoria.DataTextField = "emertimi";              
                drpdKategoria.DataBind();
                drpdKategoria.SelectedValue = drpdKategoria.Items.FindByText(emertimi).Value;
                con.Close();
                con.Dispose();
                ds.Dispose();
                ds2.Dispose();
                ds3.Dispose();
                da.Dispose();
                dk.Dispose();
                de.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

But it's showing this error: ***Object reference not set to an instance of an object***. at this line:  `drpdKategoria.SelectedValue = drpdKategoria.Items.FindByText(emertimi).Value;`

Comment: I would highly advise you look into coding defensively, specifically look into SQL injection.

Comment: How to do this? I am new at this language :/

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I guess `emertimi` contains a value that cannot be found in the dropdown list. Therefore, the `FindByText` will return `null` and getting the `Value` will result in this exception.

Test the result before you try to get the `Value`.

Also, instead of the separate `Dispose` calls, use `using` statements. And be aware of the SQL injection risk: use parameters instead.

Comment: string emertimi = "select emertimi from kategoria where id='6'"

Comment: which means tha kategoria_id = 6

Comment: Okay. Still my point remains. If you check the value that is returned by `FindByText`, is it `null`?

Comment: drpdKategoria.SelectedValue is "6"

Comment: which i think i am getting wrong because emertimi is not integer it is showing the kategoria_id and this is shown as error {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Comment: The `DataValueField` contains `id` so that is okay.

Comment: do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

That's because the item you're looking for has not been found. You should troubleshoot your code and figure out what emertimi is set to at run time.

Comment: string emrtimi= "select emertimi from kategoria where id='6'"

Comment: you are trying to select / findbytext and actual SQL statement. Is that what you are seeing in the dropdown list? if you are not seeing this in the dropdown as an option: select emertimi from kategoria where id='6', then you are not looking for the proper item...